# Generating iteration and constraint lists dynamically

Tags: iterators, constraint

I have a model for which I want to perform a set of calculations with successively deeper iterations and more constraint. In other words for a given value of a Do iterator, n, I want to:

1. perform a nested series of loops for iterators x1,x2,x3...xn which have different start and stop values, and
2. perform a calculation (e.g. FindInstance, Solve, etc.) with individual constrains on a1,a2,a3...an.

For the iterator portion I can use a variant of Sequence as

```
locs={1,4,8,13,19};
n=3;
indxs = Sequence @@ ({i[#], locs[[#]], locs[[# + 1]] - 1} & /@ 
    Range[3])
(* Sequence[{i[1], 1, 3}, {i[2], 4, 7}, {i[3], 8, 12}] *)

n=4;
indxs = Sequence @@ ({i[#], locs[[#]], locs[[# + 1]] - 1} & /@ 
    Range[4])
(* Sequence[{i[1], 1, 3}, {i[2], 4, 7}, {i[3], 8, 12}, {i[4], 13, 18}] *)
```

and then in the body of the calculation I use

```
Do[expr, Evaluate@indxs]
```

How do I do a similar thing for a list of constraints? As a MWE, when I try:

```
Clear[a, b, cons];
a = "x>0&&";
b = "t>o";
cons = ToExpression[StringJoin[a, b]]
(* x > 0 && t > o *)
FindInstance[x + t == 5 && Evaluate[cons], {x, t}, Integers]
```

I throw an error:

FindInstance::exvar The system contains a nonexistent expression o independent variables {x,t}
FindInstance[t + x == 5 && x > 0 && t > o, {x, t}, Integers]

I am using 12.3.1 for Mac OS X 11.6

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `b = "t>0";` ?  You are using `o`

Comment: Wow.  That's embarrassing.  Thanks.

Comment: To keep the question open beyond the MWE if it's okay, any ideas from anyone on how to generate a usable list of constraints of dynamically defined length n. eg. x[1]>0&&x[2]&&0...&&x[n]>0?

Comment: Try `n = 5; VectorGreaterEqual[{Array[x,n],0}]`?

Comment: ... or `n = 5; And@@ NonNegative[Array[x,n]]`?